# Where can I find low-level (platinum and below) replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to do some analysis of macro skills of players from different leagues and make some deductions from it, using replays. It's easy to find replays of pro players but for lower leagues it's not so easy.

Where I can find a lot (100+ per league) of recent (couple of months old) replays of bronze / silver / platinum / diamond players replays?

I'm fine with resources not on English (i.e. Chinese or Korean)

Comment: I was just thinking, shouldn't you be trying for replays from the same region? For example, a gold level player in Korea is probably a Masters level player in NA.

Comment: @Sorean yes, I would prefer one region so data will be representative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ended up with [gamereplays](http://www.gamereplays.org) ([search page](http://www.gamereplays.org/starcraft2/replays.php?game=33&show=search))

For example I've found there about 150 bronze replays submited since 1 Oct. That's what I've searched for.

@Sorean Thank you! <3

Answer (score 4):

You can filter out the replays they have uploaded to this website: http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays

Click on the 1v1 option and then further down you can see the league rankings, unfortunately it seems like they only have 40 at a time.

Comment: yes, I've tried to search on sc2replayed. Unfortunately there is only 3 replays of bronze after 17 sep. Similar situation for other leagues.

Comment: Sadly sites like that are driven by user uploads. You could try contacting the people of skillcraft.ca They conducted a research project a while ago that got the required information that you're looking for: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=264852 Just not sure if they would be willing to share their info.

Comment: yep. I've contacted Mark yesterday and he said they will probably share replays but after a month or so (after they completed their own analysis). But month... it's pretty long.

Comment: Yeah I can't really think or know of any other resources. I recall reading a study/write-up on Team Liquid a few months about about the correlation of macro abilities and leagues. What kind of metrics are you going for?

Comment: I'm going to analyze unspent resources / supply blocks

Comment: I guess you want diverse replays for your research but I could send you some 20 replays of gold/platinum league I did over the last days.. 
Also I have a ton of replays of master level 2v2/3v3/4v4