# Where can I get a few thousand replays sorted by league?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find low-level (platinum and below) replays?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41856/where-can-i-find-low-level-platinum-and-below-replays)

I want to analyse many replays. I have all the scripts but I lack replays.

I need a few thousand replays for every league, preferably not with the same players.

Are there any mappacks that I can use or are there any sites that I can automatically crawl with custom scripts to get such replays with curl or wget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://drop.sc/replays

Very simple, filterable by league. Should be everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this two (I also [searched](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41856/where-can-i-find-low-level-platinum-and-below-replays) for such pack not so long ago :) ):

- [replayladder](http://www.replayladder.com/site/replays/s/1v1)
- [gamereplays](http://www.gamereplays.org/starcraft2/replays.php?game=33&show=search)